# Prefix and suffix to wrap a Eva field?

Tags: entities

I have a eva which contains a view in a node. What I want to do is adding prefix and suffix to wrap around the eva field.

I tried to do that in hook_node_view(), but the $node does not contain any info about the eva field.

So how can I do that?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/ds Module

Comment: And should you do as @PravinAjaaz suggest, then just do away with EVA and use DS's dynamic field.